# Cannot resolve method ‘newInstance'

Tags: java, android

I'm getting following error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'newInstance(com.example.ghazalitodo.AddReminderActivity, int, int, boolean)
```

This is my code:

```
public void setTime(View v) {
    if (mCurrentReminderUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "click again on the reminder list to set time alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(this, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    tpd.setThemeDark(false);
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
}

// On clicking Date picker
public void setDate(View v) {
    if (mCurrentReminderUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "click again on the reminder list to set date alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.new Instance(this, now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, forgive me if I'm wrong. I'm not familiar with those views. However, I think you should use:

```
TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this, null, 
        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
```

And

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog (this, null, now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Let me know If this would help. Otherwise, I'll delete my answer

**EDIT**

I guess you copied the code from some library (which extends a `DialogFragment`). That's why you are having some conflicts.

In order to make your code work using default implementation of those `Dialog`, you can use:

```
public void setTime(View v) {
    if (mCurrentReminderUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "click again on the reminder list to set time alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this, null,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    tpd.show();
}

// On clicking Date picker
public void setDate(View v) {
    if (mCurrentReminderUri == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "click again on the reminder list to set date alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog (this, null, now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dpd.show();
}
```

Comment: when I add ur changes A new error has occurred " Cannot resolve symbol 'tpd' in : tpd.setThemeDark(false); tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog"); and : show( ) in Dialog cannot be applied : dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdial

and "Cannot resolve method 'setThemeDark(boolean)'"